# Network map GeoIP is Blocked. Does not show country flags in Germany and the country selection won't work

Tags: relays, vidalia, configuration, censorship, blocked-services

I'm living in Hungary the network map there works perfectly. In Germany I think its blocked 
by the internet provider. Tested 2 wifi HotSpot, always the same problem show up, only flags. The ExitNodes {us,ru} function won't work with general country selection with TORRC file method.

[image: TOR geoip map wont work]

Comment: Do you use Tor browser bundle?

Comment: No im using vidalia with tor relay and im using with normal Firefox ESR browser proxycap combination about long time.Im need the flash player and the Map too so im use the tor this way.